# on windows Mysql native extension prob in ruby on rails gem time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems

As I'm new to ruby on rails,need help of pro's,in first app installation,as I'm using Mysql DB on my system,i installed its gem also,but Im getting this error when I doing Bundle install for a new project app.
This below **error happens when** bundle install is on stage of:

```
Installing mysql2 (0.2.13) with native extensions
```

C:\Sites\proj2>bundle install
    Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
    Using rake (0.9.2)
    Using abstract (1.0.0)
    Using activesupport (3.0.9)
    Using builder (2.1.2)
    Using i18n (0.5.0)
    Using activemodel (3.0.9)
    Using erubis (2.6.6)
    Using rack (1.2.3)
    Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
    Using rack-test (0.5.7)
    Using tzinfo (0.3.29)
    Using actionpack (3.0.9)
    Using mime-types (1.16)
    Using polyglot (0.3.2)
    Using treetop (1.4.10)
    Using mail (2.2.19)
    Using actionmailer (3.0.9)
    Using arel (2.0.10)
    Using activerecord (3.0.9)
    Using activeresource (3.0.9)
    Using bundler (1.0.15)
    **Installing mysql2 (0.2.13) with native extensions** C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/li
    b/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Fai
    led to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

```
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
/gems/mysql2-0.2.13 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.
13/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/install
er.rb:486:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/install
er.rb:486:in `build_extensions'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/install
er.rb:159:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/l
ib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/b
in/bundle:13
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19

C:\Sites\proj2>
```

Answer (score 2):

mysql2 0.2.13 was released without binaries for Windows. Because of that, compilation is required.

Since you're using RailsInstaller, you already have pretty much all the components to solve this, but I will recommend you read a blog article I posted about compiling mysql/mysql2 gem on Windows:

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Then, you can `bundle install` and since the gem was already installed, it should be working afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much. This seems to be the problem with RailsInstaller and WAMP on 64-bit Windows 7. Your blog post with connector works perfect, and also for mysql2 gem.

Comment: I have windows 7 32 bit. What should be the command to install mysql2 adapter when i already have mysql server 5.5.16 through WAMP?

Comment: @noobcode same commands, see the blog article. The compilation of mysql or mysql2 gem is the same as long you use MySQL Connector/C and not the MySQL headers/libs from your installation.