# 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application error with Ruby (1.9.3) on Rails(3.2.3) with MySQL(5.5) on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I cannot seem to run a rail application configured to MySQL.  When I run the project, I get the following error:

`193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/mysql_api.so`

I've noticed others have hit this but I didn't find any solutions that worked for me.  Here's what I've tried so far:

- Copying `libmysql.dll` to the ruby bin folder
- Tried older version of MySQL (5.0)
- Checked the ImagePath for MySQL on regedit

Can anyone provide guidance here?  Is this just a lost cause?  Does using Linux or other versions of Ruby/Rails/MySQL combo fix this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but... Rails is barely usable under Windows. If you need to do your work on a Windows box, I recommend running Rails on Linux in a VM using VMWare or VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks that you installed the binary pre-compiled version of MySQL gem, which requires an specific version of MySQL to be installed.

More important, it requires an specific version of `libmysql.dll` be available in the `PATH` so the gem can use it.

I would recommend you uninstall the pre-compiled gem and proceed with the manual compilation steps described here:

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

This has been answered before too:

[Ruby Gem for mysql 5.5 in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897898/ruby-gem-for-mysql-5-5-in-windows/7903348#7903348)

[Is Datamapper's dm_mysql_adapter gem supported on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164926/is-datamappers-dm-mysql-adapter-gem-supported-on-windows/8171711#8171711)

[Finally installed MySQL for Rails in Windows 64 bit, and now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328476/finally-installed-mysql-for-rails-in-windows-64-bit-and-now/7335364#7335364)

[on windows Mysql native extension prob in ruby on rails gem time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275061/on-windows-mysql-native-extension-prob-in-ruby-on-rails-gem-time/7275738#7275738)

Hope that helps.