# Rails install 'Bundle' throws up error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I've just tried installing `Ruby on Rails` via the [RailsInstaller for Windows](http://railsinstaller.org). All went absolutely fine, until I tried creating my first app. Basically I run

```
rails new 'first_app'
```

and it creates all the appropriate files but throws up this error message when trying to run 'bundle install'

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
36:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/RailsInstaller
/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/openssl.so (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (
required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remot
e_fetcher.rb:316:in `connection_for'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remot
e_fetcher.rb:368:in `request'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remot
e_fetcher.rb:203:in `fetch_http'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remot
e_fetcher.rb:213:in `fetch_http'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remot
e_fetcher.rb:231:in `fetch_path'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_
fetcher.rb:265:in `load_specs'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_
fetcher.rb:231:in `block in list'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_
fetcher.rb:227:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_
fetcher.rb:227:in `list'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_
fetcher.rb:150:in `find_matching_with_errors'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_
fetcher.rb:89:in `fetch_with_errors'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/depen
dency_installer.rb:110:in `find_gems_with_sources'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/depen
dency_installer.rb:228:in `find_spec_by_name_and_version'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/depen
dency_installer.rb:259:in `install'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/comma
nds/install_command.rb:121:in `block in execute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/comma
nds/install_command.rb:115:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/comma
nds/install_command.rb:115:in `execute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/comma
nd.rb:278:in `invoke'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/comma
nd_manager.rb:147:in `process_args'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/comma
nd_manager.rb:117:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_r
unner.rb:65:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I've tried re-installing but it still pulls up that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant error message here is `193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

Checkout [this answer for a previous question about the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473646/429758); it explains why the problem happens, and provides suggestions as to how to fix it.

The person who provided the answer - [Luis Lavena](https://twitter.com/luislavena) - has worked extensively to make ruby work well on windows, and is the creator of [Ruby Installer for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org).